# In Angular, on using On Push strategy for Change Detection, if the changes are made in child component then how to prevent parent from rerendering

Tags: angular, web

I am trying to understand the change detection strategy, with on push selected in it. In it the reaction of parent when child components face changes.

I tried adding

```
changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
```

in parent-component.ts file but its's not preventing the rerender on changes made in child.

Comment: Which kind of change detection do you have in the child component? What did you changed in the child component triggering the change detection?

Comment: Incrementing the value on click of the button in the child component.